# Transient annotation and error executing DDL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, ddl, transient

I use the annotation @ trasient to declare a boolean variable but when I start my spring application, I got the error as below

```
Error executing DDL "
    alter table categories 
       add column has_children boolean not null" via JDBC Statement
```

This indicates that the column of has_children should not be null but Im not sure how to set the default of boolean value to false. Any ideas ? Thanks

----Edit-----
Below is my entity code

```
 @Transient
 private boolean hasChildren;
 public boolean isHasChildren() {
    return hasChildren;
   }
    
 public void setHasChildren(boolean hasChildren) {
    this.hasChildren = hasChildren;
   }
```

Comment: Can you add the entity for more details and the service where yu creat the object?

Comment: Try: "alter table categories 
       add column has_children boolean not null default false"

Comment: Hi all I just insert the entity code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the code showing the entity, but just a heads up.
The default value of a **boolean** (primitive) is false, but the default value of a **Boolean** (the wrapper class) is null.
So it's worth checking if your variable *has_children* is created using Boolean instead of boolean

Comment: Hi I use the boolean not Boolean. Not sure why it doesnt work